# Orthorectification of Worldview 2 using Arcgis Pro 2.9: block adjustment

Tags: arcgis-pro, orthorectification

I am trying to use Arcgis Pro 2.9 to orthorectify a Worldview 2 satellite image. I have acquired the data directly from the vendor with the associated .imd, .til, .rpb files, etc. I have set up an Arcgis workplace environment and have the initial image created, but when I try to "adjust", I get the error message that the `Error Control Point table is empty`.

In the video from ESRI located [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=orthorectification%20worldview%202%20arcgis%20Pro&client=firefox-b-1-e&sxsrf=AJOqlzUcnYSapocvc5FzBV-22sLCZ2gnEA:1675975485015&source=lnms&tbm=vid&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiL0b6bp4n9AhUYMlkFHeSBD-IQ_AUoAXoECAEQAw&biw=1536&bih=711&dpr=1.25#fpstate=ive&vld=cid:8f64117e,vid:liYcbrtDhaw), the person demonstrating clicks the adjust button, and then the screen says "sit back and relax." Surprise, surprise, that didn't happen. How do add in these points from the associated Worldview data so that I can do the adjustment?

Comment: After your block adjustment you should have control points generated... https://youtu.be/EXSKbiqL1lY?t=524

Comment: This is where I am running into problems. After creating the orthomapping workspace with the appropriate .imd file. I select "adjust" and I receive the error message  `ERROR 003045: The input control point table is empty. Failed to execute (ComputeBlockAdjustment).` Clearly, Arcgis Pro is not seeing the .rpb file, and not sure how to direct it to do it, so that I can "sit back and relax."